# Django Items in a array dont show up

Tags: python, html, django

I'm having a problem with my Django project (again). I'm trying to make a feature that adds an article and then displays all of the articles as a list. What happens is that it just doesn't display it and I have no idea why.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import util
import random


def index(request):
    entries = util.list_entries()
    random_page = random.choice(entries)
return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
    "entries": util.list_entries(),
    "random_page": random_page,
})
def CSS(request):
return render(request, "encyclopedia/css_tem.html", {
    "article_css": "css is slug and cat"
})
def Python(request):
return render(request, "encyclopedia/python_tem.html", {
    "article_python": "python says repost if scav"
})
def HTML(request):
return render(request, "encyclopedia/HTML_tem.html", {
    "article_HTML": "game theory: scavs are future humans"
})
def Git(request):
return render(request, "encyclopedia/Git_tem.html", {
    "article_Git": "github is git"
})
def Django(request):
return render(request, "encyclopedia/Django_tem.html", {
    "article_Django": "this is a framework"
})
def new_article(request):
created_articles = ["lol","pls"]
return render(request, "encyclopedia/new_article_tem.html", {
    "article_Django": "this is a framework"
})
```

new_article (here I can type what I want to be in the article):

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    New Article
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Create Article</h1>
    <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8000">
        <textarea class="new_article_title_css" type="text" name="new_article_title" placeholder="This will be the title of your article!"></textarea>
        <p></p>
        <textarea class="new_article_text_css" type="text" name="new_article_text" placeholder="Write your article here!"></textarea>
        <p></p>
        <input class = "submit_new_article" type = "submit" value="create">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

index:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>All Pages</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li><a href = /{{entry}}>{{ entry }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for article_title in created_articles %}
            <li>{{article_title}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why are you looping over `created_articles` in the template? You don't seem to pass it in the context?

Comment: Do how do i prevent that?

Comment: You are passing `entries` and `random_page` in the context, similarly pass `created_articles` if you want to use it in the template....

Comment: i changed it, still doesnt work :/